# ASP.NET: Detect file download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET (C#) web application has some forms to generate reports. When the user submits some form, a PDF report is generated on PostBack and sent to the Reponse stream as a file attachment.

The duration of the report generation may vary, so when the user hits submit, I show a modal infinite-progress-dialog to let them know that their report is being generated and to keep them from pushing any other buttons.

This is all working nicely, except that I don't know when to hide the dialog. Since the response is a file download, my page is never refreshed or notified when the servicer-side report generation is finished.

Does anyone know ho to solve this?

(As a side note, I am not interested at all in any progress tracking of generation and/or download. I just want to know when to hide my "Work in progress..." dialog.)

Thank you for any advice,

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, I was working on something similar with exporting an Excel sheet almost a year ago and in my experience, it's not possible, because when the file is generated, there is no way to detect when is completed the task or not.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a code sample.

Comment: Easiest work-around I've always used is to have the PDF open via a link rather than a postback and have that link open in a new window/tab.  Then the user sees the *browser's* progress and, when complete, the new tab disappears.  No doubt you'll dismiss this with a simple reply of "but I need a postback" - there are ways around that.

Comment: I finally worked around it by putting the report in the server cache, with an expiration of 1 minute, identified by a Guid I send to the browser. For the browser, it's now a normal postback, my Loading-Dialog is hidden upon refresh and when there's a guid, I use Javascript to transparently redirect to another .aspx that downloads the file and deletes it from cache.